# Is it possible to mark short lines _after_ compilation?

Tags: line, word-count

I am writing an academic article (2-columns), and I have a space constraint (say 8 pages). A small optimization of mine when there is only one line on the 9th page is to rephrase some paragraphs, typically when they have only one or two words on their last line.
While finding them visually is rather easy, it may be tedious (and may vary after each compilation). Is there another way to find those short lines?

I would like something like a marker (à-la-todonotes), a highlight. A log in a command line would probably be also helpful, or a word count for each line in the document.

EDIT, MWE :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}

Dapibus, nisi non porttitor iaculis, ligula odio sollicitudin mauris, non luctus
nunc massa a velit. Fusce ac nisi. Integer volutpat elementum metus. Vivamus
luctus ultricies diam. Curabitur euismod. Vivamus quam. Nunc ante. Nulla mi
nulla, vehicula nec, ultrices a, tincidunt vel, enim.

Suspendisse potenti. Aenean sed velit. Nunc a urna quis turpis imperdiet
sollicitudin. Mauris aliquam mauris ut tortor. Pellentesque tincidunt mattis
nibh. In id lectus eu magna vulputate ultrices. Aliquam interdum varius enim.
Maecenas at mauris. Sed sed nibh. Nam non turpis. Maecenas fermentum nibh in
est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
ac turpis egestas.

Duis sagittis fermentum nunc. Nullam elementum erat. Quisque dapibus, augue nec
dapibus bibendum, velit enim scelerisque sem, accumsan suscipit lectus odio ac
justo. Fusce in felis a enim rhoncus placerat. Cras nec eros et mi egestas
facilisis. In hendrerit tincidunt neque. Maecenas tellus. Fusce sollicitudin
molestie dui. Sed magna orci, accumsan nec, viverra non, pharetra id, dui.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam placerat mi
vitae felis. In porta, quam sit amet sodales elementum, elit dolor aliquam elit,
a commodo nisi felis nec nibh. Nulla facilisi. Etiam at tortor. Vivamus quis
sapien nec magna scelerisque lobortis.

Curabitur tincidunt viverra justo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed eros ante, mattis ullamcorper,
posuere quis, tempor vel, metus. Maecenas cursus cursus lacus. Sed risus magna,
aliquam sed, suscipit sit amet, porttitor quis, odio. Suspendisse cursus justo
nec urna. Suspendisse potenti. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras quis
lacus. Vestibulum rhoncus congue lacus. Vivamus euismod, felis quis commodo
viverra, dolor elit dictum ante, et mollis eros augue at est. Class aptent
taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
Nulla lectus sem, tristique sed, semper in, hendrerit non, sem. Vivamus
dignissim massa in ipsum. Morbi fringilla ullamcorper ligula. Nunc turpis.
Mauris vitae sapien. Nunc luctus bibendum velit.

Morbi faucibus volutpat sapien. Nam ac mauris at justo adipiscing facilisis.
Nunc et velit. Donec auctor, nulla id laoreet volutpat, pede erat feugiat ante,
auctor facilisis dui augue non turpis. Suspendisse mattis metus et justo.
Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Nam hendrerit lorem commodo metus
laoreet ullamcorper. Proin vel nunc a felis sollicitudin pretium. Maecenas in
metus at mi mollis posuere. Quisque ac quam sed massa adipiscing rutrum.
Vestibulum ipsum. Phasellus porta sapien. Maecenas venenatis tellus vel tellus.

Aliquam aliquam dolor at justo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi pretium purus a magna. Nullam
dui tellus, blandit eu, facilisis non, pharetra consectetuer, leo. Maecenas sit
amet ante sagittis magna imperdiet pulvinar. Vestibulum a lacus at sapien
suscipit tempus. Proin pulvinar velit sed nulla. Curabitur aliquet leo ac massa.
Praesent posuere lectus vitae odio. Donec imperdiet urna vel ante. In semper
accumsan diam. Vestibulum porta justo. Suspendisse egestas commodo eros.

Suspendisse tincidunt mi vel metus. Vivamus non urna in nisi gravida congue.
Aenean semper orci a eros. Praesent dictum. Maecenas pharetra odio ut dui.
Pellentesque ut orci. Sed lobortis, velit at laoreet suscipit, quam est sagittis
nibh, id varius ipsum quam ac metus. Phasellus est nibh, bibendum non, dictum
sed, vehicula in, sem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et
ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris sollicitudin. Duis congue tincidunt orci.
Integer blandit neque ut quam. Morbi mollis. Integer lacinia. Praesent blandit
elementum sapien. Praesent enim mauris, suscipit a, auctor et, lacinia vitae,
nunc. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
ac turpis egestas. Praesent lacus diam, auctor quis, venenatis in, hendrerit at,
est. Vivamus eget eros. Phasellus congue, sapien ac iaculis feugiat, lacus lacus
accumsan lorem, quis volutpat justo turpis ac mauris.

\end{document}
```

MWE with desired output :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}
\newcommand{\short}{\todo[inline,caption={},linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=red!25,bordercolor=red]{short ending line}}
\begin{document}

Dapibus, nisi non porttitor iaculis, ligula odio sollicitudin mauris, non luctus
nunc massa a velit. Fusce ac nisi. Integer volutpat elementum metus. Vivamus
luctus ultricies diam. Curabitur euismod. Vivamus quam. Nunc ante. Nulla mi
nulla, vehicula nec, ultrices a, tincidunt vel, enim.

Suspendisse potenti. Aenean sed velit. Nunc a urna quis turpis imperdiet
sollicitudin. Mauris aliquam mauris ut tortor. Pellentesque tincidunt mattis
nibh. In id lectus eu magna vulputate ultrices. Aliquam interdum varius enim.
Maecenas at mauris. Sed sed nibh. Nam non turpis. Maecenas fermentum nibh in
est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
ac turpis egestasi.
\short

Duis sagittis fermentum nunc. Nullam elementum erat. Quisque dapibus, augue nec
dapibus bibendum, velit enim scelerisque sem, accumsan suscipit lectus odio ac
justo. Fusce in felis a enim rhoncus placerat. Cras nec eros et mi egestas
facilisis. In hendrerit tincidunt neque. Maecenas tellus. Fusce sollicitudin
molestie dui. Sed magna orci, accumsan nec, viverra non, pharetra id, dui.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam placerat mi
vitae felis. In porta, quam sit amet sodales elementum, elit dolor aliquam elit,
a commodo nisi felis nec nibh. Nulla facilisi. Etiam at tortor. Vivamus quis
sapien nec magna scelerisque lobortis scelerisque lobortis.

Curabitur tincidunt viverra justo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed eros ante, mattis ullamcorper,
posuere quis, tempor vel, metus. Maecenas cursus cursus lacus. Sed risus magna,
aliquam sed, suscipit sit amet, porttitor quis, odio. Suspendisse cursus justo
nec urna. Suspendisse potenti. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras quis
lacus. Vestibulum rhoncus congue lacus. Vivamus euismod, felis quis commodo
viverra, dolor elit dictum ante, et mollis eros augue at est. Class aptent
taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
Nulla lectus sem, tristique sed, semper in, hendrerit non, sem. Vivamus
dignissim massa in ipsum. Morbi fringilla ullamcorper ligula. Nunc turpis.
Mauris vitae.
\short

Morbi faucibus volutpat sapien. Nam ac mauris at justo adipiscing facilisis.
Nunc et velit. Donec auctor, nulla id laoreet volutpat, pede erat feugiat ante,
auctor facilisis dui augue non turpis. Suspendisse mattis metus et justo.
Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Nam hendrerit lorem commodo metus
laoreet ullamcorper. Proin vel nunc a felis sollicitudin pretium. Maecenas in
metus at mi mollis posuere. Quisque ac quam sed massa adipiscing rutrum.
Vestibulum ipsum. Phasellus porta sapien. Maecenas venenatis tellus vel tellus.

Aliquam aliquam dolor at justo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi pretium purus a magna. Nullam
dui tellus, blandit eu, facilisis non, pharetra consectetuer, leo. Maecenas sit
amet ante sagittis magna imperdiet pulvinar. Vestibulum a lacus at sapien
suscipit tempus. Proin pulvinar velit sed nulla. Curabitur aliquet leo ac massa.
Praesent posuere lectus vitae odio. Donec imperdiet urna vel ante. In semper
accumsan diam. Vestibulum porta justo. Suspendisse egestas commodo eros.

Suspendisse tincidunt mi vel metus. Vivamus non urna in nisi gravida congue.
Aenean semper orci a eros. Praesent dictum. Maecenas pharetra odio ut dui.
Pellentesque ut orci. Sed lobortis, velit at laoreet suscipit, quam est sagittis
nibh, id varius ipsum quam ac metus. Phasellus est nibh, bibendum non, dictum
sed, vehicula in, sem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et
ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris sollicitudin. Duis congue tincidunt orci.
Integer blandit neque ut quam. Morbi mollis. Integer lacinia. Praesent blandit
elementum sapien. Praesent enim mauris, suscipit a, auctor et, lacinia vitae,
nunc. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
ac turpis egestas. Praesent lacus diam, auctor quis, venenatis in, hendrerit at,
est. Vivamus eget eros. Phasellus congue, sapien ac iaculis feugiat, lacus lacus
accumsan lorem, quis volutpat justo turpis ac mauris.

\end{document}
```

The `\short` commands are here to produce my desired visual output, I would like a package to compute the line length and hightlight only lines below a threshold (say 20%).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Please can you add a MWE? See this link: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: You might be able to do something with \parendskip.

Comment: Have a look to the `savepos` module of the `zref` package: I think you can implement what you want rather easily by means of the `\zsaveposx` and `\zposx` commands that that module defines.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a proof of concept. You do need to put `\short` after every paragraph manually for now, which I agree is not ideal, but I couldn't find a way to hook it to the end of every paragraph safely without affecting other elements in the document that use `\par`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}

% ----------------------------------
\usepackage{linegoal}

\newlength\myEOLlen
\newcommand{\printshort}{%
    \todo[inline,caption={},linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=red!25,bordercolor=red]{short ending line}%
}
\newcommand{\short}{%
    \setlength\myEOLlen{\linegoal}%
    \dimen0=\dimexpr1pt*\myEOLlen /\columnwidth\relax
    \ifdim\dimen0<.8pt
        \ifdim\dimen0<0pt
            \ifdim-\dimen0<.2pt
                \printshort%
            \fi
        \fi
    \else
        \printshort%
    \fi
}
% ----------------------------------

\begin{document}
    Vivamus eget eros. Phasellus congue, sapien ac iaculis.\short

    Vivamus eget eros. Phasellus congue, sapien ac iaculis feugiat.\short

    Vivamus eget eros. Phasellus congue, sapien ac iaculis feugiat, lacus lacus
    accumsan lorem, quis volutpat justo turpis ac mauris.\short

    \newpage
    Vivamus eget eros. Phasellus congue, sapien ac iaculis feugiat, lacus lacus
    accumsan lorem, quis volutpat justo turpis ac mauris.\short

    Vivamus eget eros. Phasellus congue, sapien ac iaculis feugiat.\short

    Vivamus eget eros. Phasellus congue, sapien ac iaculis.\short
\end{document}
```

[image: pic]